# How to debug a jQuery nested sortable draggable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

The first part allows you to first drag an element into a sortable div, which is working fine. I then want to have that div become sortable as well so I can drag new elements (parts) into those.

That part works fine too, except sometimes if you reorder the elements (the darker ones) it wont let you put a part back into it until you either reorder them again, or try and put it in one of the other elements and go back to it.

It's kind of hard to explain, but here's a screen-cast: http://screencast.com/t/Ls2ksVY4Q

The demo is at: http://jsfiddle.net/9MXWp/

Here's the relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#the-grid').sortable({
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            if( $(ui.item).has('.close').length == 0 ) {
                $(ui.item).prepend('<a href="#" class="close" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x</a>');
            }

            $('.part-holder', ui.item).sortable({ 
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    if( $(ui.item).has('.close').length == 0 )
                        $(ui.item).prepend('<a href="#" class="close" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x</a>');
                } 
            }); 

        }
    });

    $('#sidebar > ul > li.part').draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
        connectToSortable: '.part-holder',
        addClasses: false
    }); 

    $('.drag-element').draggable({
        revert: 'invalid',
        helper: 'clone',
        connectToSortable: '#the-grid',
        addClasses: false
    });

    $('#update-list').click(updateList);
});
```

---

### Recipe that seems to duplicate the problem (in FF 3.6):

1. Drag *Element 1* to the staging area.
2. Drag *Element 2* to the staging area; place it before element 1.
3. Drag a *Part* inside *Element 1*.   ☞ Sometimes the page will fail right here. ☜ ☣
4. Drag a *Part* inside *Element 2*.
5. Now drag *Element 2* to be after *Element 1*.
6. ☞ Drag a *Part* inside *Element 1*; it won't work. ☜ ☣
7. Drag a *Part* inside *Element 2*; it will work, and now *Element 1* accepts parts again.

Comment: That demo is kinda neat. No idea what it's for, but it's fun to play around with. :) You should post your code here as well, at least the relevant parts.

Comment: Thanks! It's going to be used for creating BOM's. The dark boxes are starting points, and an engineer will then be able to drag out various parts to create different circuits.

Comment: it seems like it for a brief moment looses track of the right `.part-holder` very strange indeed. wonder if you could update the grid somehow each time you have sortet the big black squares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok lets try this again; i added a 'connectWith' option, then wrapped the '.part-holder' sortable initializer so it doesn't get updated every time the grid is re-ordered...

```
$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {
        $('#the-grid').sortable
        ( {
            tolerance:  'pointer',
            update:     function (event, ui)
                        {
                            if( $(ui.item).has('.close').length == 0 )
                            {
                                $(ui.item).prepend('<a href="#" class="close" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x<\/a>');
                            }

                            if($(ui.item).has('.part-holder.ui-sortable').length == 0)
                            {
                                $('.part-holder', ui.item).sortable({
                                    tolerance: 'pointer',
                                    connectWith: '.part-holder',
                                    update: function(event, ui) {
                                        if( $(ui.item).has('.close').length == 0 )
                                            $(ui.item).prepend('<a href="#" class="close" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">x</a>');
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // don't recreate
                            }
                        }
        } );

        $('#sidebar > ul > li.part').draggable
        ( {
            helper:             'clone',
            connectToSortable:  '.part-holder',
            addClasses:         false
        } );

        $('.drag-element').draggable
        ( {
            revert:             'invalid',
            helper:             'clone',
            connectToSortable:  '#the-grid',
            addClasses:         false
        } );

        $('#update-list').click (updateList);
    }
);

function updateList()
{
    $('#current-list').empty();

    $('#the-grid > li').each( function(index, value) {
            $('#current-list').append('<li>' + $(value).html() + '<\/li>');
    });
}
```

with those changes, you are able to add the 'parts' to the 'part-holders'!  I did see some intermittent js errors... I have no idea why they appear, but they don't seem to interfere with the operation of the page when viewed with FF 3.6

Comment: You are, uh, adding an element with an inline event handler using jQuery? Surely that part isn't relevant to the bug?

Comment: Pro tip: in JavaScript, never put braces on its own lines, [automatic semicolon insertion](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#semicolon) will get you at some time.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, but that's not working for me in chrome or FF 3.6.

Comment: This solution does work for me.  Edited answer to make it clearer.  Will give it a couple of days to see if OP changes his mind.

Comment: @Brock thanks for cleaning up my answer, I'm still very green here!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is it! It works! Thanks! -Nick

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Nick P in that I think it's a bug in sortable. The other items being sorted lose the sort-ability when sorting finishes.

I added

```
$('.part-holder').sortable('refresh');
```

before

```
$('.part-holder', ui.item).sortable({
```

which worked for me in Chrome 11, FF3.7 and FF4.0b12pre.

Comment: Works for me.  Seems more elegant too.

Answer (score 3):

seems you've uncovered a bug in sortable... a potential workaround is to recreate the '.part-holder' sortable whenever it's re-ordered...

```
$('.part-holder', ui.item).sortable('destroy');
```

put that right above

```
...
$('.part-holder', ui.item).sortable({ 
   ...
```

it's a hack, but hey it works... :)

Comment: This does not work for me.  See the duplication recipe I added to the question, above.

Comment: @brock ic,in light of your recipe, my hack is total bunk... updating with something that works a bit better...

Comment: Wait, just tried this one for the hell of it and it works! This one does, and the other one doesn't. Thanks so much!

Comment: @ifightcrime this one isn't a complete solution unfortunately... If you try brock's steps it doesn't work, because the wrong item is getting destroyed in that example.

Comment: Yea I just realized that, I'm going to take a look at the other solution and see if that takes care of it.

Comment: Gave a +1, in lieu of splitting the bounty (which is not possible) with the other answer (which was plus-oned earlier).